# Обозначение ссылки

Tags: html

Добрый день! Что обозначает ссылка

```
<a href="#!/page_More"></a>
```

А конкретно интересует "#!" - что это? где и как используется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно это ссылка на якорь.

По клику перейти к элементу с id="xxx"

```
<a href="#xxx">Перейти</a>

<div id="xxx">Какой-то блок</div>
```

Хотя в Вашем примере, скорее всего мы имеем дело с Ajax...

Answer (score 2):

Это для поисковиков придуман "костыль", чтоб индексировать сайты на ajax'е.

- Google: [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)
- Яндекс: [Индексирование AJAX-сайтов](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=1125296)

Comment: Нашёл самый обычный html сайт, скачал, смотрю... Страницы сайта прописаны в index.html... а ссылаются через !#